# Allowing "User" group members to install drivers

Tags: installation, drivers, users, permissions

My problem is next. I am system admin in company of about 150 computers. All xp professional, all users. I can't afford to give anyone power user status because they're practically idiots, and will install all sorts of garbage.

But, in one department I have a need for driver installing abbility.

So my question to you is next. Is there any way to permit them to install drivers while staying in restricted "user" group?

there is no domain either.

thank you, Boris :)

Answer (score 0):

Eh-m, driver installation is kernel 'modding', it requires Administrator privs. You may create admin accounts with password 1-day expiration, and grant users install anything with your permission.

Dirty but handy :) No better ideas though.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so you've got a ton of XP desktops (150?) that AREN'T domain members. In the words of the famous mechanic... "oh, well THERE'S your problem!"

Alright, so you're going to build an active directory domain and join everyone to it Real Soon Now, right? But until then, you've still got this problem.

Do they need to continually install drivers? Like, not just once, but several times, as in "they need to constantly play with new hardware"? o_OTync is correct in that it requires administrative privileges.

I might suggest that if your users need to do this on a repetitive basis, that you give them administrative access, and for the love of God, create system images and use those to (re)deploy the machines if/when your users screw them up.

How many users are you talking about having as the exception here?

Comment: Well, I'm not gonna build a domain (no matter how bad I wish to, and I do) beacuse whole system is based on Novell netware, and there can't be two domains. So I'm stuck with novell dinosaur.
No, they don't need to constantly install drivers but often they come with external HDD's.
Well, that's a problem with images. I can;t create backups for all of them simply 'cause i don't have enough backup space on server (and a**holes won't let me buy another server or at least 2TB HDD's), so I'm doing that only for the "important" computers.

Comment: Problem with giving them administrative privileges is that, that these are almost all journalists, and they are nosey, often bored (you know what that means, when users are bored), and rather stupid.
Solution so far i giving them power user status, and installing EXE lock software solution, which protects me from executing stuff at least.
If there's no better solution in means of regediting or gpediting (for every computer individually - yes, I do realize the amount of PITA that drags along) I'm gonna have to settle with this.

Comment: That sucks, Boris. I'm sorry :-/